# Customizing an Imported Styled-Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have an `Icon` component that I'm importing into a Contact Page.  I want the `Icon` component to have unique styles for just that page.  I am also using `Styled-Components`.

As such, I thought I would extend the Icon component after importing it as follows:

```
import { Icon } from 'Elements'

const ContactIcon = styled(Icon)`
   // Unique CSS Styles
`

<ContactIcon glyph={Email} screen="Email" />
```

The problem is that the Icon component is not getting registered - as we can see if we take a look at the html that gets output:

```
<span class="ContactForm__ContactIcon-eDVBAa fAJSOh"></span>
```

If, however, I use the original `Icon` Component then everything works.  I.e., this works:

```
<Icon glyph={Email} screen="Email" />
```

And here is the html that the `<Icon>` component generates:

```
<span class="Icon__IconLink-hOjoyw ewcGUr"><span class="Icon__ScreenReader-cKVXXE lfVDCI">Email</span><svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 512 512" height="1em" width="1em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M464 64H48C21.49 64 0 85.49 0 112v288c0 26.51 21.49 48 48 48h416c26.51 0 48-21.49 48-48V112c0-26.51-21.49-48-48-48zm0 48v40.805c-22.422 18.259-58.168 46.651-134.587 106.49-16.841 13.247-50.201 45.072-73.413 44.701-23.208.375-56.579-31.459-73.413-44.701C106.18 199.465 70.425 171.067 48 152.805V112h416zM48 400V214.398c22.914 18.251 55.409 43.862 104.938 82.646 21.857 17.205 60.134 55.186 103.062 54.955 42.717.231 80.509-37.199 103.053-54.947 49.528-38.783 82.032-64.401 104.947-82.653V400H48z"></path></svg></span>
```

As further background info, here is the original `Icon` component that I am importing:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'


const ScreenReader = styled.span`
  // CSS Styles
`

const IconLink = styled.a`
  // CSS Styles
`
export const Icon = props => (
  <IconLink href={props.goTo} {...props}>
    <ScreenReader>{props.screen}</ScreenReader>
    <props.glyph />
  </IconLink>
)
```

I should also add that the Icons are being provided by `react-icons`.  That is what the `glyph` prop refers to.

So, I am wondering -- why won't this work when I use Styled Components to give a unique style to the imported React Icon component?